# How to specify in Parametric Plot that variables are on circle?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have 2 functions

```
a=2;
zx[x_, y_] := x + (a^2*x)/(x^2 + y^2);
zy[x_, y_] := y - (a^2*y)/(x^2 + y^2);
```

I want to draw a parametric plot of (zx,zy). Where x and y are on the circle of radius 1. So I tried this way

```
ParametricPlot[{zx[x, y], zy[x, y]}, 
  Element[{x, y}, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]]
```

and

```
ParametricPlot[{zx[x, y], zy[x, y]}, 
  {Element[x, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]}, 
  {Element[y, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]}]
```

Both are not working.kindly help me to plot the graph.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica version 12 . I tried this
 With[{x = Cos[t], y = Sin[t]}, ParametricPlot[{zx[x, y], zy[x, y]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]] , it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
Clear[a, zx, zy]

a = 2;
zx[x_, y_] := x + (a^2*x)/(x^2 + y^2);
zy[x_, y_] := y - (a^2*y)/(x^2 + y^2);

ParametricPlot[{x, y} = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
 {zx[x, y], zy[x, y]},
 {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

Or this

```
Clear[t]
With[{x = Cos[t], y = Sin[t]},
     ParametricPlot[{zx[x, y], zy[x, y]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
]
```

Here is a method that uses `Manipulate` to change the radius of a `Circle`, but it is much too slow.

```
Manipulate[Show[Region[

   ParametricRegion[{{zx[x, y], zy[x, y]},
     {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, radius]},
    {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}]

   ], Frame -> True,
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-8, 8}}],
 {radius, 1/2, 3/2}]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. with  
Clear[t] . It worked. Is there a way , do the same without using {x = Cos[t], y = Sin[t]}. I wanted to use Circle[r] function and later use in manipulate to see what happens with varying r.

Comment: I'm able to use Manipulate function for radius of circle by introducing r in {x =r Cos[t], y =r Sin[t]} as well. I was curious to use Circle[] function. to specify x and y are on the circle.